# Outside stylesheet css not work in the shadow dom (HTML Web Component)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

```js
        class MenuListItem extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        //create a shadow root
        let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        //create tags we need in the component
        let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        let pic = document.createElement('img');
        let itemTitle = document.createElement('h6');
        let itemDesc = document.createElement('span');
        let bCell = document.createElement('div');
        let price = document.createElement('div');
        let btnWrapper = document.createElement('div');
        let btnSlef = document.createElement('button');
        let btnTxt = document.createElement('span');
        
        //set style
        this.setAttribute('class', 'col-lg-4 col-6');
        wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'menu-item menu-grid-item');
        pic.setAttribute('class','mb-4');
        itemTitle.setAttribute('class','mb-0');
        itemDesc.setAttribute('class', 'text-muted text-sm');
        bCell.setAttribute('class', 'row align-items-center mt-4');
        price.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-6');
        btnWrapper.setAttribute('class', 'col-sm-6 text-sm-right mt-2 mt-sm-0');
        btnSlef.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm');
        

        
        //get attrubite
        //console.log(this.getAttribute('test'));
        let item_name = this.getAttribute('item-name');
        let item_desc = this.getAttribute('item-desc');
        let item_price = this.getAttribute('item-price');
        let item_img = this.getAttribute('item-img');
        
        function addCartOnClick(){
            let curItem = {item_name: item_name, item_desc:item_desc, item_price:item_price, item_img:item_img, note: ''};
            window.localStorage.setItem("currentItem", JSON.stringify(curItem));
        }
        
        
        //put value in to the tags
        itemTitle.innerHTML = item_name;
        itemDesc.innerHTML = item_desc;
        price.innerHTML = '$ ' + item_price;
        pic.setAttribute('src', item_img);
        btnTxt.innerHTML = "Add To Cart";
        btnSlef.addEventListener("click", addCartOnClick);


        //format realte elements
        shadow.appendChild(wrapper);
        wrapper.appendChild(pic);
        wrapper.appendChild(itemTitle);
        wrapper.appendChild(itemDesc);
        wrapper.appendChild(bCell);
        bCell.appendChild(price);
        bCell.appendChild(btnWrapper);
        btnWrapper.appendChild(btnSlef);
        btnWrapper.appendChild(btnTxt);
    }//constructor end
}//class end 

//regsiter the custom tags
customElements.define('menu-list-item', MenuListItem);
```

the code above is where i would like to define a custom html tag. every thing works perfectly, expect the style for those class name i set them to is not working(all those class alrady have css code for them from bootstrap). when i write them as html code it is work just fine.

[image: a294aeda61ab778ea9ee7dbaaf416bf]

And here is how I use them in `Body` HTML

```
<menu-list-item
item-name="Test Food" 
item-desc="Beef, cheese, potato, onion, fries"
item-price="9.00"
item-img="assets/img/products/product-burger.jpg"
style="display: block;"
></menu-list-item>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
    <!-- Menu Item -->
    <div class="menu-item menu-grid-item">
        <img class="mb-4" src="assets/img/products/product-pizza.jpg" >
        <h6 class="mb-0">Broccoli</h6>
        <span class="text-muted text-sm">Beef, cheese, potato, onion, fries</span>
        <div class="row align-items-center mt-4">
            <div class="col-sm-6">Price: $9.00</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-sm-right mt-2 mt-sm-0"><button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-target="#productModal" data-toggle="modal"><span>Add to cart</span></button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Update: the problem is in the costum tag css code seems not working, even in html code and it  have same class name

Comment: What is the tag/selector that you are targeting `this` in your script above?

Comment: ```class MenuListItem extends HTMLElement```
is my costum tag html class

Comment: Which is <menu-list-item> in the end

Comment: just have no clue why css style code not apply to those class in my custom tag

Comment: Are you intending or actually using a js framework to handle custom tags? Like bulma, material, vue, foundation etc?

Comment: No, this is pure javascript.

Comment: I dont think (I may be wrong, more than likely lol) that you cant just use custom html tags as a final document output without a client side js to render those custom tags into valid html?

Comment: for some reason i have to use only javascript, otherwise i have to code everthing over again, and there not really much thing in this website i try to add

Comment: why do you want to use a custom HTML tag?

Comment: I hear you man but you are using bootstrap which uses jQuery, but if you are only using pure js in conjunction with bootstrap 4 you cant throw in custom html tags without anything else

Comment: well, this did work out, just no style apply to this custom tag, just like what i have in my picture

Comment: because i want to create something like a component and use it over and over again

Comment: I maybe totally wrong, but i'm 80% sure you can't use custom html tags unless you got a reactive js client side framework to render these custom tags into valid html markup.

Comment: Actually I see your newly posted code, the valid html is not wrapped/closed in the custom html tag `<menu-list-item>`, this question might be out of my experience. Not sure of this pure js custom tag format. Sorry for wasting your time maybe some one else can help you out.

Comment: I did some research, custom tag will be render as 'shadow dom', so inside of it will not effect by the code outside. so in this case is just simpily can/t see the css code  . and thank you for help!!! 
@joshmoto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

###### Here's [some basic about 'Shadow Dom'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)!

In a nutshell, Inside of shadow dom, element can't see any code outside of the container. the best soultion i found so far was code below:

Simplely create a link tag to the style sheet just like what we did in nomal html. whatever the style files you are using, you import them one more time.

```
const linkElem = document.createElement('link');
linkElem.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkElem.setAttribute('href', 'style.css');

shadow.appendChild(linkElem);
```