# Issues with css not rendering while using a shadow DOM

Tags: css, typescript, google-chrome-extension, vite

I am making a chrome extension, using Vite, TypeScript, and React that makes it easier for teachers at my high school to edit lesson plans.

Essentially my school uses Moodle as a LMS and the CSS that Moodle uses is different from the CSS Mantine uses. So I am trying to modify the HTML of the lesson plan page editor to have 5 rich text editors instead of one.

This is what it looks like before the modification

[image: image prior to running code]

and this is the image after running the code

[image: lesson plan editor after running code]

Some CSS is missing because the rich text editor is copy pasted [from here])https://mantine.dev/x/tiptap/) thus I decided to use a shadow DOM, but even after using the shadow DOM as seen here, this is the root of my app (RTE is rich text editor and it is directly copy pasted from Mantine)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import RTE from "./pages/RTextE";
import "@mantine/tiptap/styles.css";
import "@mantine/core/styles.css";
import "./content.css";
import { MantineProvider } from "@mantine/core";
(() => {
  console.log("hello from extension");
  const DETECT_EDITING_QUERY = `#id_content_editor_label[for="id_content_editor"]`;

  if (!document.querySelector(DETECT_EDITING_QUERY)) return;
  const original_content = document.querySelector(
    "#fitem_id_content_editor"
  ) as HTMLDivElement;
  original_content.style.display = "none";
  const reactRoot = document.createElement("div");
  const shadow = reactRoot.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
  original_content.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", reactRoot);
  const link = document.createElement("link");
  link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  link.setAttribute("href", "content.css");
  shadow.appendChild(link);
  ReactDOM.createRoot(shadow).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <MantineProvider>
        <RTE title="slooga booga zooga" />
        <RTE title="slooga booga zo" />
        <RTE title="slooga booga zo" />
        <RTE title="slooga booga zo" />
      </MantineProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
})();
```

issues are still present
below is content.css

```
/** @format */
@import "@mantine/tiptap/styles.css";
@import "@mantine/core/styles.css";`
export default {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-preset-mantine": {},
    "postcss-simple-vars": {
      variables: {
        "mantine-breakpoint-xs": "36em",
        "mantine-breakpoint-sm": "48em",
        "mantine-breakpoint-md": "62em",
        "mantine-breakpoint-lg": "75em",
        "mantine-breakpoint-xl": "88em",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

here is the elements tab of the shadow DOM when I run the code

[image: Shadow DOM]

I already tried following this thread [Outside stylesheet css not work in the shadow dom (HTML Web Component)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64869363/outside-stylesheet-css-not-work-in-the-shadow-dom-html-web-component) but it does not work.

Comment: `'content.css'` should be chrome.runtime.getURL('content.css') and it must be listed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).